# Is there any way to create a "one time use" attribute in a servlet session?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, attributes

In one of my Servlets, I'd like to pass a `message` to a JSP if there is an error.

For example, if the page is loaded and everything is normal, the JSP will print nothing for the line

```
<p class="text-center red">${message}</p>
```

But if the Servlet does set a `message` attribute, I want the `message` to be displayed in the page.

I tried turning the attribute off after forwarding to the JSP page, but it's not working

```
   request.getSession().setAttribute("result", "No reports from New York State today please");
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/resources/jsp/create_report.jsp").forward(request, response);
   request.getSession().setAttribute("result", null);
```

Is there any way to set an attribute that appears on only one JSP page and then disappear or automatically deactivate? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't put it in session? When you do, you'd need to use a filter to remove it after the current req finishes, or before the next one begins.

Comment: Why not put the attribute in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the  previous answers has stated use request instead of session.

Change:

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("result", "No reports from New York State today please");
```

to

```
request.setAttribute("result", No reports from New York State today please");
```

and also in your JSP use JSTL and not scriptlet:

```
<p class="text-center red">${result}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

*"One time use"* is the definition of the request attributes (one time meaning serving one request).

If you need "one time use", store it in the request using [ServletRequest.setAttribute()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) and [ServletRequest.getAttribute()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)).

Javadoc of `ServletRequest.setAttribute()`:

> Stores an attribute in this request. Attributes are reset between requests. This method is most often used in conjunction with `RequestDispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the attribute into the `HttpServletRequest` and not into the `Session`

`request.setAttribute("result", "No reports from New York State today please");`

And in your JSP simply:

`<%=(String)request.getAttribute("result")%>`